# MySQL Trigger with Multiple IF Statements

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, sql-update, database-trigger

I am new to this and cant seem to find a situation similar to mine and Im sure the answer is simple.

I have two columns, one is a predefined licenseplate ("licenseplate") and one that will be a user inputted licenseplate ("enterlicenseplate").

I made a third column which will be the sort of error check column and will have its values inputted by a trigger. Basically if the entered license plate is the same as the predefined licenseplate, set that third column to 0, if the entered license plate is null(not inputted anything yet( set that to 1, and if theres values in both and they dont match, set it 2. But i keep getting script errors. Not sure if its my syntax or im going about this all wrong.

I appreciate any help!

```
 CREATE TRIGGER MatchPlateOnUPDATE 
 BEFORE UPDATE ON wp_wpdatable_3
 FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN
 IF (NEW.enterlicenseplate is NULL) THEN
 UPDATE wp_wpdatatable_3
    SET MatchingPlates = 0;

  ELSEIF (NEW.enterlicensplate = New.licenseplate) THEN
 UPDATE wp_Wpdatatable_3
    SET MatchingPlates = 1;
ELSE UPDATE wp_Wpdatatable_3
SET MatchingPlates = 2;
END
```

Comment: I'd consider a view instead. (Or does newer MySQL have computed columns?)

Comment: You cannot update the table which fired the trigger in the trigger. In a before trigger you can update NEW. values.AND you could do this in the UPDATE anyway..BTW you don't seem to be setting delimiters which may be your first error. If you have a syntax error you should publish it in full.AND ever if needs and end if - so quite a lot wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with the `if` statement is that you are missing closing `end if;`.

But there is more: a trigger cannot action the table it was fired upon - and even if it could, then your query would basically update all rows in the table, since your `update`s have no `where` clause.

Here, you just need to modify the value of column `matchingPlates` in the record that is about to be inserted:

```
delimiter //

create trigger matchplateonupdate 
before update on wp_wpdatable_3
for each row 
begin
    if new.enterlicenseplate is null then
        set new.matchingplates = 0;
    elseif new.enterlicensplate = new.licenseplate then
        set new.matchingplates = 1;
    else 
        set new.matchingplates = 2;
    end if;
end;
//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Not sure if before update on wp_wpdatable_3 is a a different table to  UPDATE wp_Wpdatatable_3 or not..

Comment: @P.Salmon: ah yes, I did not notice that. I would take this as a typo, given other explanations that are given in the question (*I made a third column which will be the sort of error check column and will have its values inputted by a trigger.*).